# Around into something

Tags: word-meaning, parts-of-speech

> [**Around** into my field of vision] came an eye. 
>   [link of source](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=K235a2-3FQoC&pg=PT376&lpg=PT376&dq=%22around%20into%20my%20field%20of%20vision%22&source=bl&ots=CsXad8qNwr&sig=ACfU3U3VTOJBQZ-Xs9lava1koADsvg6YmA&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc4KP10sHpAhXDFogKHXjDDYMQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22around%20into%20my%20field%20of%20vision%22&f=false)
>
> He comes [**around** into my field of vision].

1) In these sentences, what part of speech is "around"? preposition or adverb?

2) What is the meaning of "around" exactly? Although I have looked into the dictionaries, I cannot determine the meaning of "around" let alone a part of speech of "around".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an adverb. You can tell because it doesn't have an object. The sense is this:
[Merriam-Webster "around" adverb (1a)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around)
"in a circle or in circumference"

The meaning: imagine standing somewhere. Everything is around you, in all directions (a full circle). You can only see forward, over about one third of the circle. Now, something moves from a position of invisibility behind you, around that circle, until you can see it.
It came **around** into your field of vision.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer. But still, I have one question. As far as I know, there are two similar types: 1) right before it  2) from under it. In 1), "right" is an adverb and it modifies "before it", a prepositional phrase . In 2), "from" is a preposition and it takes "under it", a prepositional phrase, as its object. Isn't there any possibility that "around" belongs to 2)? Basically, I agree with the idea that "around" is an adverb but I just want to be sure.

Comment: @Mcreaper No, there is no suggestion of "from under" in either of your two original sentences. Your source, describing complicated underwater action, may have some place for movement "from under", but "around into my field of vision" clearly refers to lateral movement. If it was "from under", the author could say "it came up into my field of vision", but she didn't.

Comment: Thank you. Then, what role do you think "around" play? Does it modify "into my field of vision" or play another role regardless of "into my field of vision"? Considering "Around into my field of vision" is moved to the beginning of the sentence, I assume "Around into my field of vision" acts as a constituent.

Comment: "Around" is an adverb to the verbs "came" and "comes" in your sentences. You can say "come around", "move around", "walk around", and us it with other verbs describing movement. You can also say "walk around the building"; when you attach an object to "around", it becomes a preposition, and the whole preposition phrase is then working as an adverb.

Comment: According to your analysis, do you mean [Around into my field of vision] is not a constituent? And [Around] and [into my field of vision], separate constituents, are moved into the beginning of the sentence. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, they're separate. The preposition phrase "from under it" works because the meaning of "from" is compatible with "under it" as a location. The meaning of "around" as a preposition is "avoiding", "skirting", "circling', so that it is avoiding or missing its object. That meaning is not compatible with "into my field of vision" as a complement, so they are separate modifiers of the movement.